# How can I set the top Constraint to be 20 percent of the screen height?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have an `UIImageView` in the  in the controller's view with a distance of 20% of the screen height from the top of the view. ie I want to set the 20 % of the screen height as the `top Constraint` of the `UIImageView`.

Can I implement this without adding a transparent view, which is how I do it now (by setting its height to be 20% of the screen Height), to the container view ?

Comment: Why not just set its Y origin to 20% of screen height and its height to 80% of the screen height?

Comment: @Robert I want to know if If there is any way to do it in IB/StoryBoard?

Comment: Oh sorry I don't know, I've only worked on one iOS app and i set up the entire UI programmatically (was not fun, and was not my decision).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in the IB/StoryBoard itself. Since you want the top vertical space between the image view and it's superview to be always 20% of the height of the superview, it is same as setting the image view's height to be 80% of it's superview's height and pinning the bottom of image view to the bottom of it's superview. Hence, you can eliminate that transparent view from being added.

**Steps (I'm only considering vertical constraints here):**
1. Drag a constraint from the bottom of the image view to the bottom of it's superview.
2. Drag an *equal heights constraint* from the image view to it's superview. Change the multiplier value of this constraint to 8:10 in the *Size Inspector* (Screenshot's attached below).
[image: Size Inspector]

Comment: Here we can set the top Constraint but we cannot adjust the height thereafter according to the contained image .

Answer (score 10):

Set the top constraint of your `UIImageView` to bottom of the `main view`, with constant `0`, multiplier `0.2` or `2:10`

Reason: the coordinate of your `main view` bottom is equal to the height of it ( the top most `view` of the controller).

Edit: Step by Step

1. Add constraint from top `UIImageView` to top of the `main view` (like you normally do).
2. Go into the detail of that constraint, change `main view` top to 2nd item if needed, and set it to `main view` bottom instead of top.
3. set constraint constant `0`, multiplier `0.2` or `2:10`

Comment: perfect answer. Worked.

Comment: This is the answer to original question

Answer (score 1):

Take the Spacer View at top & give its height proportional height of 20% then give top constrain to your imageView with the spacerView & Done

Comment: Thank you for replying. But that is what I do . I wanted to know if I can achieve this without any additional view added to the superView..

Comment: i do not think their is any better way to do this.

Comment: I had the same thought until I discovered constraint with different attributes, that is the best way to do this, AFAIK