# Relative Xcode Storyboard constraints

Tags: xcode, storyboard, constraints

I have an image with some elements that that I would like to put some text labels on (they are not part of the image because they will be translated). As the image will be scaled and centered in the view these labels cannot have fixed distances from e.g. left and top of the image. 
How do I set up constraints in the Storyboard where the x,y position are scaled relatively to the scaling of the image?

PS: For now I've done it programmatically - but I suppose it should be possible to do in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve to set constraints of labels with imageView

Center label horizontally with imageView
Center label vertically with imageView

Comment: Yes, it would be fine if the label should be in the center. If the label is not in the center, you will have to use an offset (the constant value) - and the problem with the offset is that it is not scaled with the image.

Comment: If you don’t want to center labels relative to imageView then you can do this.                                                                              Set align leading constraint of each label with imageView & give it some value e.g. 30 & also set align top to imageView

Comment: Yes, but same problem because the constant value is not scaled.
For example, I have and image that's 600*400 and in that image I want to put a label on an element at offset 200,100. Now the image is shown on some device and is scaled up by a factor two (so it's 1200*800). If the label is aligned with constraints to the left and top with the constant values 200 and 100 respectively the label will not be over the element.

Comment: Check this link, this might help you


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951740/how-can-i-set-the-top-constraint-to-be-20-percent-of-the-screen-height

Comment: As far as I can see, the only way to do this is to put in a "spacer view" because it's width and height can be set relative to the image - and then the label (with leading and top) should have constraints to trailing and bottom of the "spacer view".